# illegal start of expression

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have been searching all around the web to find a solution but no
luck was found. So i went to stack overflow to see some solutions but still no luck so i am posting my code to share and help me fix this. Thank you Guys!

```
public class MyDate {
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;
    private String MoInTxt;
    private int dayz;

 public MyDate(){
     this(1, 1, 1990);
 }

 public MyDate(int d, int m, int y){
     setDay(d);
     setMonth(m);
     setYear(y);
 } 
// Setter 
public String MonthToTxt() {
    int mo = month;
     switch (mo) {
            case 1:  MoInTxt = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  MoInTxt = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  MoInTxt = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  MoInTxt = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  MoInTxt = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  MoInTxt = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  MoInTxt = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  MoInTxt = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  MoInTxt = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: MoInTxt = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: MoInTxt = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: MoInTxt = "December";
                     break;
            default: MoInTxt = "Invalid month";
                     break;
    }
}

public void setMonth(int m) {
    if(m>=1 && m <=12) {
        month = m;
            if(m ==2  && LeapChecker(year) == true) {
                month = 29;
            }else{
                month = 28;
            }
    }else {
        month = 1;
    }
}


public void setDay(int d) {
    if(day>0) {
        day = d;
    }else{
        day = 1;
}

public void setYear(int yr) {
   if (yr >=1900){
            year = yr;
   } else {
            year = 1900;
    }

}

// Getter
public int getMonth() {
    return month;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year ;
}
//==============================//

public String getCompleteDate(){
    return String.format ("%s %02d, %d", MoInTxt, day, year);
}

//==============================//
public void addDays(int dey) {
    int addedDey = dey + day;
    int ToAddMos=0;
    if(addedDey <=28) {
        setDay(addedDey);
    } else {
        while(addedDey>28){
             if(month==1 || month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month==10 || month == 12){
                if(addedDey>31){
                    addedDey=addedDey-31;
                    setDay(addedDey);
                    ToAddMos++;
                }else{
                    setDay(addedDey);
                    break;
                   }
            }else if(month ==2) {
                if(LeapChecker(year) == true){
                    if(addedDey >29) {
                    addedDey = addedDey - 29;
                    ToAddMos++;
                }else { 
                    setDay(addedDey);
                    break;
                    }
                }else if(LeapChecker(year) == false) {
                    if(a>28){
                        addedDey = addedDey - 28;
                        ToAddMos++;
                    }else{
                        setDay(AddedDey);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else if(month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11){
                if(addedDey>30){
                    addedDey-=30;
                    ToAddMos++;
                } else {
                    setDay(addedDey);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void addMonths(int mon) {
    int addedMon = mon + month;
    setMonth(addedMon);
}

public void addYears(int yir) {
    int addedYir = year + yir;

    setYear(addedYir);

   }


/* Method Name: Leap Checker
 * This Method checks if that year is a leap year or not
 * 1. It checks if the year is divisible by 400
 * 2. It checks if the year is divisible by 4
 * 3. It checks if the year is not divisible by 100
 */
public boolean LeapChecker(int year){
    year = year;
    boolean isLeap =true;
      if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0))) {
          isLeap = true;
        } else {
            isLeap = false;
        }
        return isLeap;
    }
}
}
```

[image: The image below is the compiler error message]

Comment: You are missing a } closing the else block right before setYear()

Comment: When you see errors like that, always look for a missing curly brace above. In the overwhelming number of cases you are going to find where it's missing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a missing closing curly brace at the end of the `setDay()` method:

```
public void setDay(int d) {
    if(day>0) {
        day = d;
    }else{
        day = 1;
    } // <------------------ this one
}
```

Comment: This is a special category for closing questions like that: "offtopic -> typo/non reproducible".

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setDay(int d) {
    if(day>0) {
        day = d;
    }else{
        day = 1;
    }//Missing closing the else block
}
```